# Adding checkmark image with no background

Tags: jquery, image, png

I have a page with tabs along the left side.  each tab opens a form in middle of page.  When the user fills out a form correctly, I want to add a checkmark to that tab.  I have tried 10 or so different greencheck.png files and none of them are transparent. I want to avoid the grey background around the checkmark.  Am I missing something?

```
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#tabs-1">Account</a><span id='accountSpan'></span></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-2">Personal</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-3">Opportunity</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-4">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-5">Services</a></li>....
```

and the jquery to add the checkmark

```
            $('#accountSpan').html('<img src="/images/greencheck2.png" width="25px">');
```

the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to care about the png, its not because its png that it is transparent inside.
You have to check when you find one if there is a checkerboard in the background.

[image]

You can also use graphic software to be sure that the background is transparent.

```js
$('#accountSpan').html('<img src="https://findicons.com/files/icons/573/must_have/48/check.png" width="16px">');
```

```css
#tabs ul { list-style:none}
#tabs ul li { background-color:purple; padding:10px; margin-top:5px }
#tabs ul li:first-child { margin-top:0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#tabs-1">Account</a><span id='accountSpan'></span></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-2">Personal</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-3">Opportunity</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-4">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-5">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: last question.  How did you find that icon?  i need a few different icons i need to use.

Comment: @bart2puck https://www.google.com/search?q=check+icon+png+transparent&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjx1__43OH5AhULRhoKHSedBykQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=check+icon+png&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgBMgQIIxAnMgUIABCABDIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHlAAWABg3Q9oAHAAeACAAVmIAVmSAQExmAEAqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=Q0cHY7GqB4uMaae6nsgC&bih=927&biw=1920